# IOS Instagram login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, authentication, instagram

Facebook has a nice login feature. When you press the "signup with Facebook" it redirects to the Facebook app (if installed) to verify the user and send back user data.

With Instagram it is possible to login using a browser (i.e. UIWebview)and is not using the installed Instagram app for user verification. This makes it a less nice user experience.

Does anyone know if there is a way to use Instagram login in the same way that Facebook login works (so, by using the Instagram app)?